# Suppose $v$ is an eigenvector of $T$ if and only if $v$ is an eigenvector of $S$. Show that $ST=TS$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, diagonalization

Let $V$ be finite-dimensional and suppose $S$ and $T$ are diagonalizable linear operators on $V$.  Moreover, suppose $v$ is an eigenvector of $T$ if and only if $v$ is an eigenvector of $S$.  Show that $ST=TS$.

I think my approach below is right, but I just wonder why both $S$ and $T$ are diagonalizable in this problem.

My approach:

> Since $S$ is diagonalizable, there exists a list of eigenvectors of
> $S$, $v_1, ..., v_n$ that forms a basis of $V$.
>
> By the given condition, $v_1, ..., v_n$ are eigenvectors of $T$ as
> well.
>
> Thus, the following results hold. $$Sv_1= \lambda _1 v_1, Tv_1=
>  {\lambda}'_1 v_1, ..., Sv_n= \lambda _n v_n, Tv_n= {\lambda}'_n v_n.$$
>
> Also, since $v_1, ..., v_n$ is a basis of $V$, $\forall v \in V$,
> $v=a_1v_1+...+a_nv_n$ for some $a_1, ..., a_n \in \mathbb{F}$.
>
> Thus, $\forall v$, $$STv=a_1 \lambda _1 {\lambda}'_1 v_1 + ... + a_n
>  \lambda _n {\lambda}'_n v_n=TSv$$ This implies, $ST=TS$.
> $\blacksquare$

However, as I mentioned in the beginning, I wonder why both linear operators are diagonalizable in this problem, while I only used that $S$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: Diagonalizability is helping you in claiming that there exists a basis of $V$ that is made up of eigenvectors of $S$.

Comment: Do you know that a linear operator is diagonalisable if and only if it has a basis of eigenvectors?

Comment: @AnuragA I understand that part, but why do you think $T$ is also given as a diagonalizable operator in this problem? Is it just for making us begin from any linear operator when starting the proof?

Comment: @WillM. Yes, that is the reason why I claimed eigenvectors $v_1, ..., v_n$ are forming a basis of $V$. What I was wondering was why both $S$ and $T$ were given as diagonalizable operators, while I only used the fact $S$ is diagonalizable in this proof. I guess it is just for convenience that allows us to begin from any operator (if my guess is right.)

Comment: Suppose that $T$ and $S$ have no eigenvectors - which is possible over the reals, say- and don't commute.

Comment: @john Actually we only need one of the operators to be given as diagonalizable. With the condition given about eigenvectors to be the same, you get diagonalizability of the other operator from it.

Comment: I wrote my comment so that assuming $S$ is diagonalisable and $T$ has the same eigenvectos is the same as assuming $S$ and $T$ are diagonalisable and they have the same eigenvectors. So yeah, you can get rid of the hypothesis if you want but it is not giving you more or less.

Comment: @WillM. I now clearly understand that they are equivalent statements. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formally, you're right. The weaker hypothesis $S $ diagonalizable together with $v$ is an eigenvector of $S$ if and only if it is an eigenvector of $T$ would be sufficient.

However, those two hypothesis immediately imply that $T $ is also diagonalizable as you proved it.